# CRM 2013 Plugin not updating my field

Tags: c#, plugins, dynamics-crm

I've created a CRM plugin that's supposed to grab values from entities on a subgrid and keep a running total. Everything seems to work correctly except that the field on the form I'm looking at isn't being updated. When I uncomment out the call to service.Update(entity) it gives me an infinite loop. Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong? Everything I've looked at so far seems to indicate that my code is correct so I'm at a loss. Thank you.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Activities;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Workflow;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Query;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Messages;

namespace SubGrid_Calculator
{
public class SubgridCalculator : IPlugin
{
    //A list is a data structure that preserves the order of the elements that are put into it. 
    //A set is a data structure that does not allow duplicate objects. Order is NOT guaranteed in a set.
    //EntityReference returns 3 properties: Logical Name, ID and Name (often, but not always the primary key)

    IEnumerable<Entity> GetRelatedEntities(IOrganizationService service, string primaryEntity, Guid primaryEntityId, string relationshipName, string targetEntity)
    {
        //the related entity we are going to retrieve
        QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression();
        query.EntityName = targetEntity;
        query.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("new_totalmonthlytext", "crmp_contract", "crmp_name");

        //the relationship that links the primary to the target
        Relationship relationship = new Relationship(relationshipName);
        relationship.PrimaryEntityRole = EntityRole.Referenced; //important if the relationship is self-referencing

        //the query collection which forms the request
        RelationshipQueryCollection relatedEntity = new RelationshipQueryCollection();
        relatedEntity.Add(relationship, query);

        //the request to get the primary entity with the related records
        RetrieveRequest request = new RetrieveRequest();
        request.RelatedEntitiesQuery = relatedEntity;
        request.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("crmp_name");
        request.Target = new EntityReference(primaryEntity, primaryEntityId);

        RetrieveResponse r = (RetrieveResponse)service.Execute(request); //was service.Execute

        //query the returned collection for the target entity ids
        return r.Entity.RelatedEntities[relationship].Entities;//.Select(e => e.Id);
    }     

    private IOrganizationService orgService;
    private TraceServiceWrapper tracingService;

    public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        //Activity code
        Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.IPluginExecutionContext context = (Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.IPluginExecutionContext)
         serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.IPluginExecutionContext));

        IOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory = (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));
        IOrganizationService service = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);
        this.orgService = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);
        OrganizationServiceContext ServiceContext = new OrganizationServiceContext(service);

        // The trace wrapper is a CRMPoint.net custom library for maching logging and tracing
        //TraceServiceWrapper trace = new TraceServiceWrapper(service, tracingService, "HttpTest"); NO idea what I'd need as my middle arg
        ITracingService tracingService = (ITracingService)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(ITracingService));             //localContext.TracingService;

        var crmTracingService = (ITracingService)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(ITracingService));

        if (crmTracingService == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException("Failed to retrieve the tracing service.");
        }
        this.tracingService = new TraceServiceWrapper(this.orgService, crmTracingService, "SubgridCalculator");


        if (context.InputParameters.Contains("Target") && context.InputParameters["Target"] is Entity)
        {
            // Obtain the target entity from the input parameters.
            Entity entity = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];

            this.tracingService.Trace("Plugin Started!");
            this.tracingService.Trace("MEssage Name: ", context.MessageName);
            this.tracingService.Trace("Primary Entity Name: ", context.PrimaryEntityName);
            this.tracingService.Trace("Primary Entity Id: ", context.PrimaryEntityId );
            this.tracingService.Trace("PluginExecutionContext: ", context);
            this.tracingService.Trace("Post Context:");
            //this.tracingService.Trace(" ", );

            // Verify that the target entity represents an HttpTest entity
            if (entity.LogicalName != "crmp_contract") //was new_httptest
                return;
            this.tracingService.Trace("Entity is Plan:");

            //var preEntityImage = context.PreEntityImages["PreImage"];
            //this.tracingService.Trace("Preimage:", preEntityImage);
            //this.tracingService.Trace(TracingItemType.PreImage, EntityTraceHelper.TraceAttributes(preEntityImage));

            //var postEntityImage = context.PostEntityImages["PostImage"];
            //this.tracingService.Trace("POSTimage:", postEntityImage);
            //this.tracingService.Trace(TracingItemType.PostImage, EntityTraceHelper.TraceAttributes(postEntityImage));
            //subgrid_ratedescriptordetail
            //crmp_contract_crmp_ratedescriptorsetdetail_Contract
            //crmp_policy for policy   crmp_contract for plan
            //crmp_ratedescriptorsetdetail for rdd

            List<Entity> results = GetRelatedEntities(service, "crmp_contract", entity.Id, "crmp_contract_crmp_ratedescriptorsetdetail_Contract", 
                "crmp_ratedescriptorsetdetail").ToList();

            decimal total = 0.000M;
            this.tracingService.Trace("About to calculate total:");
            foreach(Entity e in results)
            {
                total += Convert.ToDecimal(e["new_totalmonthlytext"]);
                Console.WriteLine(e["new_totalmonthlytext"]);
                this.tracingService.Trace(e["new_totalmonthlytext"].ToString());
            }
            this.tracingService.Trace("Total finished.");
            try
            {
                //total = total / 0;
                //entity.Attributes.Add("new_totalmonthlycostthree", total);
                this.tracingService.Trace("About to set total.");
                //entity["new_totalmonthlycostthree"] = total;
                entity.Attributes["new_totalmonthlycostthree"] = total;
                this.tracingService.Trace("Total: ", entity["new_totalmonthlycostthree"].ToString());
                this.tracingService.Trace("Total set. Abut to update.");
                this.tracingService.Trace("Entity: ", entity);
                //service.Update(entity);
                this.tracingService.Trace("Updated. About to handle success");
                this.tracingService.HandleSuccess();
                this.tracingService.Trace("Success Handled!");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                this.tracingService.HandleException(ex);
                throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException(ex.Message + " - Something went wrong.");
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem after a bit of googling. I added:

```
if (context.Depth > 1) { return; }
```

after context was instantiated. After uncommenting service.Update(entity);, it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You have to be careful with Context.Deph validation.

> You must be careful when using the Depth property as there are more complex scenarios that you may run into. For example, a data import may trigger a workflow to update the “Full Name” of a Member, which in turn will execute our plugin. In this case, the Depth will be 3 at the first execution of the plugin. If you left the code snippet above unchanged, the plugin logic will never get executed.
>   -->http://roscode.wordpress.com/2013/04/24/crm-2011-plugins-avoiding-infinite-loops/

Other Solutions would be:

1. Do not use the target entity for the update. Build an new Entity object in code, fill only the fields you need and filter the attributes which will trigger the update in pluginregistration tool.
2. Register your Plugin in Pre-Step and write the attributes to update directly into the target. No update needed.